# JQuery Draggable helper not contained

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am using the below code to init draggable, using a helper to create an easing effect. The use of the helper, however, breaks the containment and allows the draggable elements to leave their container. How might I constrain the helper to the container?

**Some more info:** The elements are contained within the left and top borders, just not the right and bottom borders.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmkVR/12/

```
        $( ".drag" ).draggable( {
            containment: con_outer,
            scroll: false,
            helper: function(){
                return $('<div></div>').css('opacity',0);
            },
            drag: function(event, ui){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    top: ui.helper.position().top,
                    left: ui.helper.position().left
                },200,'easeOutCirc');
            },
            start: function() {
                //Make the dragged item the top-most
                zindex ++;
                $(this).css("z-index",zindex);
            }
        }).each(function(index, value) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.click(function() {
                //Click only registers if the object isn't being as dragged
                if($this.is(".ui-draggable-dragging")) {
                    return;
                }
                clickPhoto(index);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can't you add the helper div to your html+css and use a selector instead? `helper: ".helper"`

Comment: I tried this, it causes the draggable divs to jump all over the place. Maybe I set it up wrong?

I simply inserted `div.helper` into the same container as the draggable divs and referenced it as you mentioned.

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qmkVR/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the helper as the `<div class="drag"></div>` by using the below code.

```
helper: function(){
            return $('<div class="drag"></div>').css('opacity',0);
    },
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qmkVR/13/